# How to add a < Back button to a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I have a simple app where I push views to the navigation. However, on one of the screens I push tab controller with two tabs. When I do this the navigation goes away when I reach the tab controller screen. On the navigation of the tab screens I would like to know how a `< Back` button.

Basically, I want to know how to manually create a `< Back` button on top left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

Then write the `goBack` method:

```
- (void)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note: There are some other initializer for UIBarButtonItem. Choose any one as your need.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: So i need an image that mimics the `< Back`. Can you point me where to download it from?

Comment: There is a lot of images like this. See this: https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=back